# Formatting Excel cell from number to text in rails

Tags: excel, ruby-on-rails-4, roo-gem

I have made an application on which I have provide the feature to import the records from CSV and Excel file. I am using roo gem for it. The record added successfully but the problem is at the time of importing records from excel, it adds .0 to every field which is number. I don't want it because i have some fields like enrollment_no, roll_no, contact_no and it adds .0 to every filed like it made 23 to 23.0. I already had converted these filed to varchar in database and now i want to format the excel cell from number to text. It will solve my problem. Tell me how i will format the excel cell from number to string using rails.

Here is my code for importing the file:

student.rb :

```
def self.import(file, current_organization_id)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    record = Student.find_by(:organization_id => current_organization_id,:enrollment_no => row["enrollment_no"]) || new
    record.organization_id= current_organization_id
    record.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
    record.save!
  end
end


def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

students_controller.rb :

```
def import
    Student.import(params[:file], session[:current_organization_id])
    #puts @session[:current_organization_id].inspect
    redirect_to students_path, notice: "Record imported Successfully."
  end
```

new.html.erb :

```
<%= form_tag import_students_path, multipart: true do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file , :required=> true%> <br/>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" , :class => "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar in my application but the import is made easier by importing only from csv.

It seems that **cell type** is a pretty [common problem in Roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo/issues/53) and there are few workaround suggested using regex or char to include in your cell.

My solution it would be much easier:

```
# student.rb

COLUMNS_TO_STRING = ["organization_id", "enrollment_no", "contact_no"] # and so on


def self.import(file, current_organization_id)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    row = clean_for row, COLUMNS_TO_STRING
    record = Student.find_by(:organization_id => current_organization_id,:enrollment_no => row["enrollment_no"]) || new
    record.organization_id= current_organization_id
    record.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
    record.save!
  end
end

def self.clean_for row_as_hash, string_columns_array
  row_as_hash.each do |key, value|
    if string_columns_array.include?key
      row_as_hash[key] = value.to_i.to_s
    end
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

- get the index of the columns you want to format differently
- convert the value imported from float to integer
- convert the integer to string